# Nodejs Express global login middleware wont execute at all (app.use)

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

for what ever reason this global middleware wont execute, even though i've implemented this in many other projects, is not that it doesnt work is just that it doesnt even execute

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
      console.log("this is executing")
      res.locals.usuario = false;
      if(req.session.usuario){
        res.locals.usuario = req.session.usuario;
        return next();
      }else if(req.cookies.email){
        let usuario = usersDatabase.find(usuario => usuario.email == req.cookies.email); 
        delete usuario.password
        req.session.usuario = usuario;
        res.locals.usuario = usuario;
        return next();
      } else{
        return next();
      }
    });
```

app.js

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs'); 
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require("express-session")
const cors = require('cors')

const indexRouter = require('./routes/indexRoute');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/usersRoute');

let app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({secret:"Javascript FrontEnd Validation"}));
app.use(cors());


app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// app.use(middleware);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

let usersDatabase = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './database/users.json')));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("this is executing")
  res.locals.usuario = false;
  if(req.session.usuario){
    res.locals.usuario = req.session.usuario;
    return next();
  }else if(req.cookies.email){
    let usuario = usersDatabase.find(usuario => usuario.email == req.cookies.email); 
    delete usuario.password
    req.session.usuario = usuario;
    res.locals.usuario = usuario;
    return next();
  } else{
    return next();
  }
});

module.exports = app;
```

stack overflow wont let me publish such a tiny description so here it goes a hole bunch of letters, please make my middleware go

Comment: I believe middleware/endpoints execute in the order they are registered...Maybe try moving it up higher in your `app.js`?

Comment: @David784 Yes, you're correct. You should submit your answer. He should still abstract that middleware code into its own module, import it, and then use it before any of the routes. 

I'm assuming he noticed how error handling middleware was placed in the bottom of application files and assumed you should do that with custom middleware, but the reason why error handling middleware is placed at the bottom is because the general purpose error handler is not dependent on the sequence of execution in the request and response lifecycle.

Comment: @GandalfTheGrey that's correct now it works just fine, thanks!